# How to handle ZeroMQ C++ listener IP address change

Tags: c++, docker, dns, zeromq

How can I detect/handle IP address change of a ZeroMQ C++ connected logger service from the logger client?

Like when the Docker container restarts in the Swarm mode?
I use this string on the server `tcp://*:20000` while using `tcp://logger_svc:20000` on the client(s).

It seems it doesn't resolve the `logger_svc` hostname on each call/caches the IP, so I guess my only way is to detect the change on the client.

I tried wrapping the socket.send call in a try catch block, but it never catches a thing, not event when I bring down the logger service:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        // Perform your ZeroMQ send operation here
        m_socket->send(msg, ZMQ_DONTWAIT);

        // If successful, break out of the loop
        break;
    }
    catch (const zmq::error_t& e) {
        // Handle the send error, e.g., log or take necessary actions
        printf("zeromq send error, will try reconnecting");

        // Sleep for a delay before attempting reconnection
        Sleep(1000);

        // Attempt to reconnect by closing the socket and establishing a new connection
        m_socket->close();
        m_socket->connect(GetLogListenerUri());
    }
}
```

I guess that's normal, since a MQ is in between, not a direct TCP connection, but I'm lost at what to try next.

I only have these socket options available:

```
#define ZMQ_AFFINITY 4
#define ZMQ_IDENTITY 5
#define ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE 6
#define ZMQ_UNSUBSCRIBE 7
#define ZMQ_RATE 8
#define ZMQ_RECOVERY_IVL 9
#define ZMQ_SNDBUF 11
#define ZMQ_RCVBUF 12
#define ZMQ_RCVMORE 13
#define ZMQ_FD 14
#define ZMQ_EVENTS 15
#define ZMQ_TYPE 16
#define ZMQ_LINGER 17
#define ZMQ_RECONNECT_IVL 18
#define ZMQ_BACKLOG 19
#define ZMQ_RECONNECT_IVL_MAX 21
#define ZMQ_MAXMSGSIZE 22
#define ZMQ_SNDHWM 23
#define ZMQ_RCVHWM 24
#define ZMQ_MULTICAST_HOPS 25
#define ZMQ_RCVTIMEO 27
#define ZMQ_SNDTIMEO 28
#define ZMQ_LAST_ENDPOINT 32
#define ZMQ_ROUTER_MANDATORY 33
#define ZMQ_TCP_KEEPALIVE 34
#define ZMQ_TCP_KEEPALIVE_CNT 35
#define ZMQ_TCP_KEEPALIVE_IDLE 36
#define ZMQ_TCP_KEEPALIVE_INTVL 37
#define ZMQ_TCP_ACCEPT_FILTER 38
#define ZMQ_IMMEDIATE 39
#define ZMQ_XPUB_VERBOSE 40
#define ZMQ_ROUTER_RAW 41
#define ZMQ_IPV6 42
#define ZMQ_MECHANISM 43
#define ZMQ_PLAIN_SERVER 44
#define ZMQ_PLAIN_USERNAME 45
#define ZMQ_PLAIN_PASSWORD 46
#define ZMQ_CURVE_SERVER 47
#define ZMQ_CURVE_PUBLICKEY 48
#define ZMQ_CURVE_SECRETKEY 49
#define ZMQ_CURVE_SERVERKEY 50
#define ZMQ_PROBE_ROUTER 51
#define ZMQ_REQ_CORRELATE 52
#define ZMQ_REQ_RELAXED 53
#define ZMQ_CONFLATE 54
#define ZMQ_ZAP_DOMAIN 55
```

Comment: Might this be an operating system thing? For example, Windows caches DNS lookups, and takes a while to notice that a name is now resolving to another address (one can fix it by asking Windows to flush its DNS cache). You can spot the difference using nslookup - which explicitly goes and asks the DNS server - and, say, just pinging the hostname which picks up whatever IP address the OS has got stashed. Maybe similar on other OSes?

Comment: But aside from that, if a ZMQ endpoint disappears (e.g. because a docker container goes away) and reappears, the ZMQ socket at the the surviving end will enter reconnection mode immediately, and will try and reestablish a connection ASAP. You shouldn't have to close it and reconnect it - it should be doing that for you.

Comment: @bazza so you're positive zeromq c++ will not cache the IP somewhere in its code?

Comment: I've not ploughed through all of https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/src/socks_connecter.cpp, but I note that the first thing `zmq::socks_connecter_t::connect_to_proxy()` does is re-resolve the address if it already had been. So, I'm at least faintly confident that it's not cached.

Comment: Thanks, I've found a mention regarding DNS caching for Windows images here: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27499, possibly that's the culprit, as you've suggested.

Comment: No worries, and good luck, I hope you get it sorted.

Comment: I'll keep ploughing through the ZMQ source code - I scrolled down further and found lots of files like "tcp_connector.cpp", which might be more relevant. I've not had a look in that one yet - need to get the day done - but I'll come back to it later.

Comment: Yes, I'm now positive. In https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/src/tcp_connecter.cpp, `zmq::tcp_connecter_t::open()` disposes of any existing resolved address, and this method is also called when a socket is being reconnected.

Comment: Thanks, but what if socket->connect happens only once in my code, and the target zmq listener changes its IP?

Comment: Ah, you need to understand what's actually going on under the hood. When you call socket->connect(), all that does is tell the socket management thread to start trying to make the actual connection. Normally, that'd work first time. If for any reason the network connection stops working, the management thread will in the background start trying to re-connect the connection, re-resolving the IP address at each attempt. Take a look at https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter2/, section "Plugging Sockets into the Topology", bullet point 4:

Comment: Quote: "The network connection itself happens in the background, and ZeroMQ will automatically reconnect if the network connection is broken (e.g., if the peer disappears and then comes back)." This is one of the many fantastic things about ZMQ because it takes care of so many resiliency issues for you, transparently! You can get information about the progress of a connection through the built-in socket monitor functionality. The code I checked was that related to exactly how the management thread (re)establishes a connection, and found that it re-resolves each time.

Comment: So, that's what's made me think you might have a DNS caching thing going on underneath your application. This is on Windows? If so, you could test this as follows. Run your application, tear down the container, start it again on a different IP address, application fails to connect. On the Windows cmdline, type `ipconfig /flushdns`, which should make your socket reconnect (if my theory is correct)

Comment: If that were the problem, then you can disable DNS caching with a registry setting. There's similar options for Linux wrt systemd's resolved, etc.

Comment: If this was the issue, and you didn't want to set registry entries on Windows, you could modify ZMQ's address resolver to programmatically flush the DNS cache (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007372/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-win32-apis for how to do that). There's probably a way on Linux via dBus to tell systemD to flush its cache, and you could build that into ZMQ's address resolver. Maintaining a separate bespoke ZMQ source code base would be a pain.

Comment: Yes, this is a Windows app.
I believe I tried the ipconfig /flushdns, while also trying the nslookup logger_svc which seems to resolve the new IP without a problem on cmd prompt. However, it seems the source states that the ZMQ lib in this project is at least from 2018(maybe older), could this be the problem? Related to this, when I try to cmake 0MQ with cmake -G "Visual Studio 12" .. I get  This project doesn't contain the Configuration and Platform combination of Debug|Win32

Comment: If this does turn out to be the issue, it might be worth suggesting to the ZMQ project that the library grows a callback feature, whereby an application can provide a method for the library to use to flush DNS whenever it wants. This feels better than building DNS cache flushing into the library, because that is OS specific, and ZMQ tries very hard to be OS-neutral. And if an application didn't care about DNS cache flushing, it needn't set the callback.

Comment: nslookup bypasses the DNS cache. I've been checking the current source code, a lot has changed since 2018! I'll re-wind the repo, see what it looked like then!

Comment: When the listener logger_svc restarts, this is how netstat -an looks:

```
    TCP    192.168.5.34:49187     192.168.5.33:20000     SYN_SENT
    TCP    192.168.5.34:49188     192.168.5.33:20000    SYN_SENT
    TCP    192.168.5.34:49189     192.168.5.33:20000     SYN_SENT
```


Before restart it was established.

Comment: Ipconfig /flushdns didn't help.

Comment: I've checked as far back as 4.3.0 (Nov 2018), and it's the same there, it re-resolves on connection attempts.

Comment: That netstat output looks consistent with the zmq::tcp_connecter_t::open() method being repeatedly called. It re-resolves every time, creates a fresh socket and tries to connect it. The sequential local port numbers are indicative of this. Presumably, the remote IP address is right? I've also now checked back to the beginning of 2018, same re-resolve mechanism is there. This is proving tricky!

Comment: Can you try setting the ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_IVL socket option to 2000, and the ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT to 1000 also? This will cause ZMQ to ping the connection every two seconds, and time out after 1 second if a pong or other traffic hasn't arrived in reply. I'm just wondering if, for some reason, ZMQ is having a hard time working out that the docker end has disappeared and not really getting into reconnection mode. The explicit ping/pong makes it check more thoroughly for a live connection to a working remote process in the absence of any other traffic.

Comment: I have edited my question with the list of ZMQ socket options, I don't see yours available.

Comment: Aha, then we must be dealing with libzmq 4.1 or older, which is now very old! I'll take a look through that, see it does cache addresses, if I can find the code. The github repo seems to go back only as far as 4.2...

Comment: It does go back far enough - 14/Oct/2014 - and it's still re-resolving on reconnection attempts. Personally, I'd try updating to the latest version of the library. That might not fix the problem but you could try the HEARTBEAT socket options then. Or, if you can add it to the application, use zmq_socket_monitor(), which allows you to get notifications of what's going on inside the monitored socket. That should be giving a ZMQ_EVENT_DISCONNECTED when the docker container is closed. If not, then that'd suggest that it's not seeing the connection break; an upgrade + heartbeats would be needed.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me, it turned out to be DNS caching after all. I've built the latest ZMQ lib, but even then the connection failed, so i tried ipconfig /flushdns and after a couple of seconds, log entries started appearing.
I've addes these two to my powershell init script for all containers, it's working for now:
```New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters' -Name MaxCacheTtl -Value 0 -Type DWord
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters' -Name MaxNegativeCacheTtl -Value 0 -Type DWord```

Comment: Woohoo! Well done, glad we got there! And, you're very welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @bazza's comments, the solution in my case was to skip DNS caching using these two commands (updating the ZeroMQ cpp lib could have also helped):

```
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters' -Name MaxCacheTtl -Value 0 -Type DWord
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters' -Name MaxNegativeCacheTtl -Value 0 -Type DWord
```

Based on a discussion from Github:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27499